# Ruby sorting issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to sort the array `@users` by the number of `posts` they have. Here's what I have in my controller:

```
@users = User.includes([:posts]).where("user_type = ?", "A")        
@users.sort {|a,b| (a.posts.size <=> b.posts.size)}
```

Here's what I have in my view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.name %>: <%= user.posts.size %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

My list of users is pretty random and is not properly sorted. If I'm not mistaken, the `<=>` operator is what I want to use. I want to return `1` if `a` has more posts than `b`, `-1` if `b` has more posts than `a` and `0` if `a` and `b` have the same number of posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the missing bang.

```
@users.sort! {|a,b| (a.posts.size <=> b.posts.size)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `sort` instead of `sort!`. `sort!` will sort `@users` in place.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see:

Instead of using `sort`, use `sort_by` when you have to dig into an object. It shouldn't be a big speed up for the short method chain you're using, but it can add up:

```
@users.sort_by! {|a| a.posts.size }
```

If you're retrieving your data from the database, instead of sorting in Ruby, use [`order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) or `order_by`, depending on which is supported, to have the DBM sort the data in the order you want. DBMs are optimized for sorting and can do it extremely fast.

Comment: I would love to use order or order_by ... but I need to order by the size of a separate query.